# How to insert image inside fleatherfield using imagepicker?

Tags: android, flutter, image, mobile, embed

How can I integrate the imagepicker library into the fleatherfield? I simply cannot understand the documentation written in the examples itself on how to properly integrate embedding images.

> _pickImage

```
Future<void> _pickImage() async {
final returnedImage = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery); // You can also use ImageSource.camera
setState(() {
  _selectedImage = File(returnedImage!.path); // _selectedImage actual output of selected image
  _selectedImagePath = returnedImage.path; // convert to String of returnedImage.path to be able to save
});
```

}

> Fleatherfield

```
FleatherField(
                controller: _controller,
                focusNode: _focusNode,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: _selectedBackgroundColor,
                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 10.0),
                  hintText: 'How\'s your heart?',
                  hintStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium!.copyWith(
                      color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer),
                ),
                embedBuilder: _embedBuilder,
              ),

              // How can I change this to be able to put the selected image inside the fleatherfield?
              // _selectedImage != null
              //     ? Image.file(_selectedImage!)
              //     : const Text("Please select an image"),
              // const SizedBox(height: 10),

Positioned(
            bottom: 120,
            right: 0,
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              heroTag: 'uploadButton',
              onPressed: () {
                _pickImage();
              },
              child: const Icon(Icons.upload),
            ),
          ),
```

> fleather documentation widget builder

```
Widget _embedBuilder(BuildContext context, EmbedNode node) {
  if (node.value.type == 'image' &&
      node.value.data['source_type'] == 'assets') {
    return Padding(
      // Caret takes 2 pixels, hence not symmetric padding values.
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 4, right: 2, top: 2, bottom: 2),
      child: Container(
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage(node.value.data['source']),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  throw UnimplementedError();
}
```